# Does Stripe Payment Intent Id need to be kept secret?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for payments in my app. There are two Ids: `payment_method_id` and `payment_intent_id`. I noticed that when I try to use a payment_method with a different Stripe Customer, it doesn't let me, so my guess is that it is not that secret. Are payment_intent_ids secret? If I store the payment_intent_id in a database for each transaction is that bad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `PaymentIntent` id (pi_123456) is really just an identifier and doesn't have to be kept secret. No one can do anything with the id unless they have your Secret API key or the `PaymentIntent`'s `client_secret`.

It's definitely common practice to store the `PaymentIntent` id in your database as a reference to the object in the API. It's similar to how you can store a `Customer` id (cus_123) or its `PaymentMethod`s ids (pm_123) in your database.

Comment: If an attacker gets control of my customer id and payment method id combination, couldn't they trigger a payment for that customer? i'm also trying to understand if a customer saved a card with us initially, what information is needed for a hacker to trigger a pamynet on behalf of someone else?

Comment: To trigger a payment they need you Secret API key which should be stored safely on your server. As for charging a previously saved card, you don't need anything specifically really. But again you need your Secret API key to explicitly configure the PaymentIntent for that specific customer id first which is done server-side.

Comment: yeah lets say they trigger a request to our backend where they input another person's customer id and payment method id... then they would be able to charge right? I think the point here is that if the api is authenticated and you can guarantee only that the person triggering the call can use their own stripe customer/paymentmethod id then you are safe.. but otherwise if your api is not authenticated then having stripe customer id and paymentmethod id publicly *could* be dangerous. but i agree with you, not straightforward

Comment: That's correct, you're supposed to know the right customer id server-side, not trust it from the client. Usually your customer has an account in your app/website and you know their real customer id based on a session or a cookie for example